# extbase action only called if i am logged in backend

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

When I am logged in Backend, the content of "Anzeigenverwaltung" is rendered. "Anzeigenverwaltung" is my extension that calls the "listAction", which works fine. Action is called, template for this action is rendered.

But if i logout from Backend then "Anzeigenverwaltung" is not being rendered.

The content "Test" is always being rendered.

It is a fresh TYPO3 8.7 installation.

Is there any security related configuration that does not allow to call the action without an BE session?

[image]

Here is some code of my extension:

```
// setup.txt
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {

    templateName = myextension
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Templates

    variables {

        content < styles.content.get
        content.select.where = colPos = 0
    }
}

plugin.tx_myextension {
    persistence {
        storagePid = 7,10
        classes {
            TYPO3\Myextension\Domain\Model\Location.newRecordStoragePid = 10
        }
    }
}

// myextension.html
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="content">
            <f:format.raw>{content}</f:format.raw>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

// extbase controller
class PackageController extends \MyVendor\Myextension\Controller\AbstractController {
    public function listAction() {
        $packages = $this->packageRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('packages', $packages);
    }
}

// listAction template
<f:for each="{packages}" as="package">
    <f:link.action pageUid="{settings.single}" action="single" arguments="{package: package}">    
</f:for>
```

Update:

```
// ext_tables.php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'TS', 'MyExtension');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('RTE.default.preset = full');

$EXTDIRFULL = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($_EXTKEY);
$EXTDIR = 'EXT:myextension/';
$LANG = 'LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml' . ':';
$PID_DEFAULT = 10;


\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'MyVendor.' . $_EXTKEY, 
    'Package', 
    $LANG . 'admanager'
);

include_once $EXTDIRFULL . 'Configuration/TCA/package.php';

// FlexForm PackageController
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$_EXTKEY . '_package'] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($_EXTKEY . '_package', 'FILE:EXT:package/Flexform/package.xml');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(array($LANG . 'admanager', $_EXTKEY . '_package'), 'list_type', $_EXTKEY);


// ext_localconf.php
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyVendor.' . $_EXTKEY, 
    'Package', 
    array(
        'Package' =>
            'list,single' 
    )
);


// flexform
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <general>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Display type</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <switchableControllerActions>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Display</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <items type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:listview</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">Package->list;Package->single;</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </switchableControllerActions>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </general>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes from Backend and Install Tool with no success.

Comment: Can you show your `ext_localconf.php` and `ext_tables.php`?

Comment: I have updated my Question.